# Add raw / uninterpreted content to Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have prepared a `.Rmd` file with some R code, which I knit in Rstudio into a `.md` file. This `.md` file will, in turn, be pushed into a GitHub repository in order to produce a GitHub page (using the [GitHub pages system](https://pages.github.com/)) with a specific layout.

The issue I have is that when I specify the layout in my Rmarkdown file, e.g. with the following code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: github_document
layout:mylayout
---
```

It does not appear in the `.md` file, and so the Github pages do not use my layout. To include my layout, I need to modify the `.md` file manually to add the following header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document
layout:mylayout
---
```

I would like to not have to modify my `.md` file manually, i.e. to include the aforementioned header automatically when I knit my `.Rmd` file into a `.md` file.

I have unsuccessfully tried numerous methods, including `print`, `cat`, `paste` as well as writing r chunk codes with argument `results="asis"`.

Is there a possibility to put raw content in a `.Rmd` which will not be interpreted at all?

Here is a very simple example of my `.Rmd` file:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: github_document
layout:mylayout
---

# I would like to add the next part at the beginning of my .md file,
# but it is always removed or altered such that it does not appear 'as is' in the .md
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document
layout:mylayout
---

# After this header comes the content of the file
Content with R code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GFM does not support YAML metadata, so `github_document` doesn't support it, either. Only `md_document` supports YAML, e.g.,

```yaml
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_github
    preserve_yaml: true
layout: mylayout
---
```

But if you use Jekyll and Github Pages, you may consider using **blogdown** instead of knitting posts individually: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/jekyll.html Then you won't need to specify the `output` field in YAML. The output will be `.md`, and all your YAML metadata will remain untouched.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that works very fine. Good suggestion as well on using blogdown! Thanks!